# Problem in solving a question related to symmetric group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**The question is** :

> For $n \geq 4$ prove that $S_n$ the symmetric group is generated by $n-1$ elements of order $2$.

How can I solve it?Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you know about symmetric groups? There are many different ways to prove this depending on your knowledge. Could you provide which instruments and results one is allowed to use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many choices of generators that will work, but let's pick an easy one: $(1,2),(1,3),\ldots,(1,n)$.

Given a permutation $f$ considered as a function $f:[1,n]\to[1,n]$, let $g_1$ be the identity. Suppose $f(2)=i$. Then $g_2=g\circ (1,i)\circ (1,2)$ satisfies $g_2(2)=i$. Suppose inductively that we have $k>1$ and $g_k$ satisfying $g_k(p)=f(p)$ for $2\leq p\leq k$. If $g_k(a)=f(k+1)$, then $g_{k+1}=g_k\circ (1,a)\circ (1,k+1)$ satisfies $g_{k+1}(p)=f(p)$ for $2\leq p\leq k+1$.

When we finally reach $g_n$, there's no choice but for $g_n(1)$ to be equal to $f(1)$, so we're done.